# What are the minimal axioms required to define a set of all bijections?

Tags: set-theory

What is the minimal set of axioms that is required to show that for a countable set $A$, the following definition is a set $C = \{ f \colon A \rightarrow A \mid f \textit{ is bijection} \}$?

Can we show the existence of this set $C$ based on ZF without the axiom of choice (and indeed get all the functions we want), or do we require ZFC? Or maybe something weaker than ZFC?

Comment: You don't use axioms to *define* things, you use them to *prove* things. Are you asking about what axioms are needed to prove that $C$ is in fact a set?

Comment: [ZF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) is way sufficient, for *any* set $A.$

Comment: @NoahSchweber yes, exactly. sorry for this confusion.

Comment: You just need to show that $A$ x$ A$ is a set as $f$ is a subset of $A$ x $A$. I think you need the power set axiom , the axiom of pairing, the axiom of extensionality and the axiom of comprehension. You'd need to write out the proof to double-check!